# Running Tensorboard in a Docker Container, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard.context'

Tags: python, docker, tensorboard, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to run tensorboard in  docker container.
Here are parts of my dockerfile:

```
# get base image

FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.0-gpu

...

# install tensorboard

RUN pip install tensorboard

RUN pip install -U tensorboard_plugin_profile
```

However, when I start tensorboard in the container with
`tensorboard --logdir '/log/' --host 0.0.0.0`
it returns following error:

```
E1203 10:17:24.945772 140395295995712 application.py:260] Failed to load plugin ProfilePluginLoader.load; ignoring it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 255, in TensorBoardWSGIApp
    plugin = loader.load(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard_plugin_profile/profile_plugin_loader.py", line 75, in load
    from tensorboard_plugin_profile import profile_plugin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard_plugin_profile/profile_plugin.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorboard.context import RequestContext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard.context'
```

When not using `RUN pip install -U tensorboard_plugin_profile` I don't get the error, however I can't use the tensorflow profiler then. The tensorboard page suggested using `pip install -U tensorboard_plugin_profile`

I would really appreciate your help!